# How to fix a sidebar in poisition and not let content overflow push down flexbox content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I stop the `#sideBar` `footer` from being pushed down to the bottom because the content is making the page scroll? I am trying to get the `footer` to display at the bottom left of the viewport height but not be affected by content that overflows and starts scrolling? At the moment the footer gets pushed down with the content but I want it fixed in position and not to be affected by overflow.

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sideBar
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: grey;
    width: 12%;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #d0cfd4;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
}

footer ul
{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0.1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0cfd4;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#content
{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<main>

  <div id="sideBar">
    <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    
    <footer>
      <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  </div>
  
</main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is such a weird way to set up a page.  But here's a few things you can change to get that working. You can not wrap it in `<footer>` but a div and just put a class to it.  and also remove `margin-top: auto;` and that should get you what you want. See here:

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sideBar
{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: grey;
    width: 12%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #d0cfd4;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.footer ul
{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0.1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0cfd4;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#content
{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<main>

  <div id="sideBar">
    <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="footer">
    
      <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  </div>
  
</main>
</html>
```

Comment: And just in case, here's some further improvements I made which you might be going for:  https://jsfiddle.net/fuzbLcen/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for here, but I think this will do.

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sideBar
{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: grey;
    width: 12%;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #d0cfd4;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
}

footer ul
{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 0.1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0cfd4;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#content
{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<main>

  <div id="sideBar">
    <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    
    <footer>
      <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  <h1>Content!</h1>
  </div>
  
</main>
</html>
```